# Insert entered form input text into paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, forms

How do I insert a person's form input text into a pre-made paragraph.

For example:
Enter Your Name: `John`

Becomes 
`<p>Hello, my name is John</p>`

Preferably on the same or another HTML page. Just like all those various web generators work.

The languages I have access to is HTML, jQuery, JavaScript and JSON

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val & http://api.jquery.com/text

Comment: Can you share what yo’ve tried so far? Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: SMH at the down votes. The original post and answer below were helpful for me today. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan), Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to achieve this.

Try this:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#text').text('Hello, my name is ' + $('#nameInput').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="nameInput">Your Name:
  <input type="text" id='nameInput'>
</label>
<button id='btn'>Show Name</button>

<p id='text'></p>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Now, in the grand scheme, I'd like to have several of these boxes, maybe a half dozen, and then generate the results throughout a large HTML document. Would I just follow this for each text field?

Comment: Okay, so I used this, and like the snippet above, it of course worked. But then I noticed that all of the original "Hello my name..." text is inside of the jQuery code, which works great for a few lines but this one field will go into a large document several times, is it suitable to wrap this code around an entire document? Thanks.

Comment: Ahh sorry, honestly, I don't have any code, this is the beginning ha! Perhaps a form action might be easier. But thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Perhaps this may offer a better idea https://jsfiddle.net/Lkqg5qjb/

Comment: Each `input` must have unique `id`, on `click` of the button, do the same thing as explained in the example..

Comment: Hmm alrighty then, I'll keep working on it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: __Happy coding!__ Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) if it has solved the purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery:

```
$('#paragraphId').text(myText);
```

Hard to give you more specific advice without more of your code posted, but as long as your paragraph has an id and your text is stored in a variable, the above should work.

Answer (score 0):

here is the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/mt42fn3s/

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name">
<p id="result"></p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#name").keyup(function() {
            var userName = $('#name').val();
            $('#result').html("Hello My name is " + userName);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to this is to post the form back to the current page (*if* you're able to use php and forms) and retrieve them from the global $_POST variable.

```
// index.php

<?php $name = $_POST['name']; ?>

// This is your predetermined paragraph, with the name dynamically inserted
<p>Hello, my name is <?php echo $name; ?></p>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input id="name" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This way, it's much easier to add as many variables to your paragrah.

If you can only use Javacsript/Jquery, perhaps create spans with id tags to hold your information. Eg;

```
<p>Hello, my name is <span id='name'></span></p>
<p>My surname is <span id='surname'></span></p>

// jquery

var $name = $('.name').val(); // your name input box;
var $surname = $('.surname').val(); //your surname input box

$('#name').val($name);
$('#surname').val($surname);
```